# Why does OpenSSH debug2 handshake logging only on some logins, not on every login?

Tags: ssh, logs, openssh, debugging, systemd-journald

Running Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS with package openssh-server 7.6p1-4ubuntu0.5

In `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` is set `LogLevel DEBUG2`.

I get the debug2 log message of the client MACs offering part of handshake:

`May  3 18:51:05 10.10.10.10 sshd[14300]: debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5 [preauth]`

and afterwards in the same second the login log entry for user "abc" login from IP 1.2.3.4 with the same sshd PID, so I guess this login message belongs to the first debug2 log entry:

`May  3 18:51:05 10.10.10.10 sshd[14300]: Accepted password for abc from 1.2.3.4 port 51294 ssh2`

**But** I get the according (same PID, roughly same second) debug2 handshake log entry not for *every* `Accepted password` log entry, only for a small fraction of logins.

E.g. I observe a user logging in 2525 times on a day, but I can see the according `debug2: MACs ctos:` log entry (same PID, roughly same time) only for 155 of those logins.

This happens accross all user logins, so it is not user specific.

Is this a bug or a feature? Is there some handshake info cache, so full handshake is not done (or logged) on every login? How can I achieve that for *every* login the debug2 handshake log entry is made?

Comment: What do you mean by "logging in"? Where do you get the 2525 number from and where do you get the 155 number from?

Answer (score 0):

It was a systemd-journald message RateLimit effect.

The sshd logs so many messages that journald suppresses them:

`systemctl status systemd-journald`

```
May 11 19:02:50 myserver systemd-journald[303]: Suppressed 19842 messages from sshd.service
May 11 19:03:03 myserver systemd-journald[303]: Suppressed 85 messages from ssh.service
May 11 19:03:20 myserver systemd-journald[303]: Suppressed 25865 messages from sshd.service
May 11 19:03:50 myserver systemd-journald[303]: Suppressed 15138 messages from sshd.service
May 11 19:04:03 myserver systemd-journald[303]: Suppressed 148 messages from sshd.service
May 11 19:04:20 myserver systemd-journald[303]: Suppressed 31797 messages from sshd.service
```

Solution:

In `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` change line

`#RateLimitBurst=1000`

to

`RateLimitBurst=50000`

Now the filtered debug log messages always show up in syslog-ng as expected.